# Wire-tie cables

Tags: cables

Is there a name / specific type for flat-jacketed wires which come tied on consumer product cables (eg. earphone cables, power cables) ? I always collect them from the new products I buy, but I wish to buy some in a volume.

I find it the most handy thing (rather than nylon zip ties) to temporarily tie small cables, for storage, and tidying up behind the AV sets.

I see they are basically just some thicker wires, but don't think some wires I'd grab from a cat5 cable would stand against that amount of twisting.

Comment: A picture perhaps?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but do you mean twist ties like you sometimes get with freezer bags?

Comment: @jippie I searched a lot to find an image / name on google. But they come with any electronic product, you know, when you buy something with a power cord, it's usually tied with one of these, usually black or white, nylon jacketed wires. I'll look for an unboxing video, maybe I can use it to give an example.

Comment: @PeterJ Yeah, twist-tie was it. I didn't know the term. It's not necessaryly an electrical accessory, but a good management item anyway -)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Plastic coated wire twist-ties' seems to hit the right sort of thing on ebay.

Comment: Oh yeah, "twist-tie" is it, just "twist tie wires" brings a lot in a search. I just didn't know the term -) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist_tie

And frankly, cat5 and any single strand 22/24 gauge wire makes for great twist ties. I use bell wire, the blue and yellow cross connect wire that Bell Atlantic Terminal Boxes have used for decades.

[image]